# Which query performs better with Entity Framework and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Do this 2 queries equal or differ in performance?

```
var results = ctx.Products
    .Where(x => x.Category.Name == "something")
    .Select(x => new {
        ProductId = x.Id, 
        ProductName = x.name, 
        CategoryName = x.Category.Name 
    })
    .ToList();

var results = ctx.Products
    .Select(x => new {
        ProductId = x.Id, 
        ProductName = x.name, 
        CategoryName = x.Category.Name 
    })
    .Where(x => x.CategoryName == "something")  
    .ToList();
```

Would SQL Server use the correct index in the second query?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/20751723/1336590 to look at the resulting sql statements if they're different, run them both in a profiler and compare running times.

Comment: I've tested this with express profiler with 1000 records in my local machine.  They're almost the same in running times. I need to know if they're using the same index to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are equivelent in all but Syntax. Entity Framework will only resolve the result set at iteration time, and you've basically applied the same set of filters, just in a different order.